# How to avoid foreach error WebDevStudio's WDS_Taxonomy_Radio taxonomy metabox class?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

What is the correct way to use WebDevStudio's WDS_Taxonomy_Radio taxonomy metabox class?

I have included the code in my functions.php file but I'm getting an error that reads: *Invalid argument supplied for foreach() WDS_Taxonomy_Radio.class.php on line 45* so I must be doing something wrong.

The instructions on GitHub say to:

> Initialize the class (update the taxonomy slug with your own)

using the code `$custom_tax_mb = new WDS_Taxonomy_Radio( 'custom-tax-slug' );`. Of course I updated the slug to my taxonomy's. The script otherwise works.

Any help is appreciated!

Links
 1. https://github.com/WebDevStudios/WDS_Taxonomy_Radio
 2. http://webdevstudios.com/2013/07/08/replace-wordpress-default-taxonomy-metabox-with-a-radio-select-metabox/

Comment: It might be gratuitous self-promotion, but if you are just looking to convert a taxonomy to use radio buttons, I already have a plugin in the repo for that: [Radio Buttons for Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/)

Answer (score 1):

Upon initialization of the class, you need to pass two parameters:

```
    public function __construct( $tax_slug, $post_types = array() ) {
```

So what you need to do is initialize like this:

```
 $custom_tax_mb = new WDS_Taxonomy_Radio( 'custom-tax-slug', array( 'post_type' ) );
```

In the second array you need to put the name of the post types for which you want to display the meta box in the admin. This is why the `foreach()` fails.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm still getting the error. Perhaps it has something to do with my taxonomy having an underscore in it.    

`new WDS_Taxonomy_Radio( 'cfo_category', array( 'campaign', 'project' ) );`

Comment: Underscores are allowed to my knowlegde.Could you check the return value of the `register_tanonomy()' function to see if the registration has gone smoothly?

Comment: Is there a better method to your knoeldge than runing a var_dump on `$tax = register_taxonomy( 'campaign_status', 'campaign', $args );`?